# Could not load type 'NewBSN.REVIEWS_Maintenance

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.Net website production source code which was developed in .Net framework 2.0. when I tried to compile, it gave below

error 
"Could not load type 'NewBSN.REVIEWS_Maintenance'." at page directive line

```
  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="REVIEWS_Maintenance.ASPX.vb" Inherits="NewBSN.REVIEWS_Maintenance" enableViewState="True" %>
```

When I googled, I found the solution to change from Codebehind to CodeFile and set AutoEventWireup property to true.

So I changed the code as

```
  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="REVIEWS_Maintenance.ASPX.vb" Inherits="NewBSN.REVIEWS_Maintenance" enableViewState="True" %>
```

Now, got new error
Error::: Type 'REVIEWS_Maintenance' is not defined.

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Comment: you've still got `Codebehind` and not `CodeFile`

Comment: are you sure? it still says "codebehind" in your new code. please double check that you indeed changed it in your sourcecode.

Comment: Please put your code behind code

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrongly here. But I did the changes correctly (CodeFile) in solution.